# CarrierWave object update with existing file url

Tags: ruby, object, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm using **CarrierWave** for file upload in my project. At the beginning of the implementation process, we've made a mistake and eventually a bunch of objects been uploaded to s3 with minor file naming issues. This was fixed shortly for new uploads.
Now we need to fix all this (let's say thousands) CarierWave/s3 objects broken paths. 
Is there any good way to change CarrierWave object with no reuploading? 
The part with s3 path update is already done, all I need to do is to change CarrierWave object.

Tried:

```
img.update(...)
img.raw_attributes_update(...)
  ...
img.file=...
(with further internal updates to define 'skip' upload var)
```

> Note: re-uploading of all the images is our worst scenario, which I
>   really want to avoid.

Comment: were you able to find the solution to update the object without re-uploading?